# Create event table trigger in MySql

Tags: mysql

I would like  to create a trigger for event table while we make update and delete in primary table. I have a two table one is primary and another one is event table. If any change in primary table like (update and delete) the old record inserted into event table.

```
fld_id  fld_name    fld_date    fld_logid
1   vino            12/4/2014   4
2   arun            12/4/2014   4


fld_id  p_table_id  fld_name    fld_date    fld_logid
1           1           vino            12/4/2014   4
2           1           vino            12/4/2014   4
3           1           vino            12/4/2014   4
4           1           vino            12/4/2014   4
5           2           arun            12/4/2014   4
6           2           arun            12/4/2014   4
```

Answer (score 0):

> *If any change in primary table like (update and delete) the old record inserted into event table.*

You can define a `after delete` trigger on `primary_table` to record `delete` operations.
And define a `after update` trigger on `primary_table` to record `update` operations.

I am not sure about your exact requirement, but if this is to log those operations, then it would be good to have an `operation_type` and a `datetime` field in the `event_table` to record the event type and occurrence time.

If such fields are not defined in the table, you can add it as shown below:

```
alter table event_table 
    add column event_type enum( 'delete', 'update' ) not null default 2
  , add column event_time datetime default current_timestamp
```

With an assumption of having such field, I suggest following `trigger`s.
You can comment-out the field if such field is not required.

**Example 1:** ***After Delete***:

```
drop trigger if exists ad_on_primary_table;

delimiter //

create trigger ad_on_primary_table
         after delete 
            on primary_table
for each row
begin
  insert 
    into event_table ( p_table_id, fld_name, fld_date, fld_logid
                       , event_type, event_time
         )
  values ( OLD.fld_id, OLD.fld_name, OLD.fld_date, OLD.fld_logid
           , 'delete', current_timestamp -- 'delete' is @ index 1 in enum
           -- or use the following
           -- , 1, current_timestamp -- 1 is index of 'delete' in enum
         );
end;
//
```

**Example 2:** ***After Update***:

```
drop trigger if exists au_on_primary_table;

delimiter //

create trigger au_on_primary_table
         after update
            on primary_table
for each row
begin
  insert 
    into event_table ( p_table_id, fld_name, fld_date, fld_logid
                       , event_type, event_time
         )
  values ( OLD.fld_id, OLD.fld_name, OLD.fld_date, OLD.fld_logid
           , 'update', current_timestamp -- 'update' is @ index 2 in enum
           -- or use the following
           -- , 2, current_timestamp -- 2 is index of 'update' in enum
         );
end;
//
```